# Cpanel MySQL database credentials

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel, sails.js

I've purchased a web hosting and the guy gives me the link of my hosting and I've added my domain against it; now I am trying to create MySQL database in it. I've created a database in MySQL and by clicking on phpmyadmin in cpanel it navigates me to the database, but I am not able to see its credentials and so that I could write those in code or configure my navicat. I've created a database and also a user in cpanel and have assigned all the privileges to the user, but I'm still not able to access the database in navicat. My navicat configurations are:

```
User Name/IP Address: localhost
Port: 1433
User Name: database name
Password: password the cpanel give me while adding a user.
```

Please let me know where I am mistaken.

EDIT:

even the console rejects the credentials, my config_db is:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database name', 'userName', 'userPassword', {
      host:"localhost",


      dialect: "mysql", // or 'sqlite', 'postgres', 'mariadb'
      port:    1334, // or 5432 (for postgres)
 });

module.exports = {  

    dbase: sequelize,


};
```

and the image of console is:

[image: console rejecting the mysql credentials]

and the code where i'm trying to access the table and try to execute the inset sql query is (the controller file):

```
 client_login: function (req, res) {


     sequelize.query("INSERT INTO `t_user_Information` ( `id`, `user_name` , `user_password`) VALUES ('NULL', 'login' , 'passWordParam')");

              res.json({status: 'success', message: 'success' , has_agreed:resUserInfo.dataValues.has_agreed, password_reset: resUserInfo.dataValues.password_reset});
              console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Done  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')
});
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the username is actually the name of the mysql user you created, and not the host.

Comment: I've also used the username of the user i've created but still it's not connecting, even in the code i've tried it but the console says " failed to authenticate for msql " i've snapped the console and attached in the question, please have a look at edited question

Answer (score -1):

- To access your server from your local system, your server should have MySQL remove access enabled.
- Check if your Port is not blocked by some firewall.
- If you created the username and database separately in cPanel, step to next process - and assign the user to that database (both in drop down lists).

Comment: 1) how can one MySQL remote access enable at cpanel?
2) how can one check if it's port is not in blocked by some firewall?

Comment: i think i don't have access to command shell in my cpanel and if it is then please let me know where it's, please guide me @bimal

Comment: All these are available in cpanel. If not, you may have received too limited features. You do not need command lines here. Pleade check http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/MySQLDatabases and http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/enable-remote-access-customer-database-251951.html.

Comment: @BimalPoudel well one thing is for sure, he wants to connect his db in Navicat or remote and on remote connection the host couldn't be the localhost and the documentation you prefered is not telling the host name of the domain for remote connection.